# Adjusting OR for confounding variable with non linear interaction

Tags: logistic, interaction, odds-ratio, predictor, adjustment

I have looked for similar cases but couldn't really find the answer to my question.

I want to assess the impact (with an OR in logistic regression) of a predictor **X1** on a binary response variable **Y** and adjust for a confounding variable **X2**.

The thing is **X1** is known to vary in non linear way depending on **X2** (e.g. a polynomial degree 3 could describe the relation between **X1** and **X2**, i.e. **X1** = f(**X2**) where f() is a degree 3 polynomial)

So my question is, how do I adjust the OR of **X1** to account for dependency on **X2** ? What kind of formula should I use in the logistic regression ?

Thank you so much in advance !

Comment: Conceptualize this as formulating a grid of x1,x2 points for getting predicted values, and make a plot with confidence bands.  This easily handles complex situations and is discussed at length in my RMS course notes - http://www.fharrell.com/p/blog-page.html

Comment: Thank you @FrankHarrell for your response and my apologies for the delay. I had a look at your course notes and your very nice book RMS. I understand the construction of a 3D shape (X1-X2-prediction) with splines and additional constraints on the global form of the 3D shape, but can't link that to your confidence bands suggestion. Also my problem might be summarized by a more general question : can we adjusted an OR when there is some interaction term ? Sorry if this is a really novice question, stats is not really my background :) Thank you so much !

Comment: Confidence bands are only easy to plot/see when one of the two varying variables is varied only over discrete levels, to get a series of curves with confidence bands.  But you need to think of effects of interest in terms of exactly which predicted values (or their differences) would give you that.

Comment: Correct link is https://hbiostat.org/rms